# android Listview button

Tags: android, button, resources

I am trying to add a button in my list view. But the button is not showing up. I am using json parsing to take data from my server. I am using hashmap and listviews. Moreover i cannot adda button in the list view too. Here's my code:

```
package acb.xiynove;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImgJsonActivity extends ListActivity
{
    TestServiceActivity obj = new TestServiceActivity();
    String newString;
    int len;
    Button btn,btn1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        newString=obj.readTwitterFeed();
        // define the list which holds the information of the list
        List<Map<String, Object>> resourceNames =
            new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        // define the map which will hold the information for each row
        Map<String, Object> data;

        // hard coded numbers retrieved from
        // http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/R.drawable.html
        try {

           JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(newString);
           len = rootArray.length();
//         List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(len);

          for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
          {
             data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String x="";

            JSONObject post = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);
            x+= " " + post.getString("u")+ " " + post.getString("s") + " " + post.getString("e") + " on " + post.getString("pd") + " with " + post.getInt("a") + " ";                      
        data.put("line1", x);
            data.put("img", R.drawable.boy);

            data.put("btn", btn);
            data.put("btn1", btn1);
            resourceNames.add(data);
            //   listContents.add(x);

          }
//        myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewfont, listContents));     

           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
           }

          SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(
                    this,
                    resourceNames,
                    R.layout.row,
                    new String[] { "line1", "img", "btn", "btn1" },
                    new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.img, R.id.btn, R.id.btn1} );

                setListAdapter(notes);

    }
}
```

Here's the row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vw1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">    

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>



        <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Show Interest"
        android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="Ask Query"
        android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should add button in Row xml file. and android:focusable=false.

Comment: @Samir nope... it is does not help!

Comment: is only the buttons are not showing up or the list? what about the textviews ?

Comment: @Rakhita everything else is showing.. except the buttons!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want buttons inside list items, put a button in the list_item.xml .

make a custom adapter :

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
 .
 .
 .
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                    parent, false);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listButton);
       //find and assign other views here...
       convertView.setTag(holder);
   }else{
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
  // assign values to all view elements..
  holder.button.setTag(position);
  holder.button.setOnClickListener(this);
  }  //end of getView

public void onClick(View v) {
    int postition=(Integer)v.getTag(); // now you know wich button in list was clicked.
//do whatever you want. cheers!
}
}
```