# button in listview android

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android ListView with delete button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750380/android-listview-with-delete-button)
>   [android Listview button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224088/android-listview-button)

Okay .. I will be simple and straight.. Please tell me how to add button in a list view. I have gone through various questions about this topic but none seems to help.

I have json format of data and am using hashmaps to read the values in the listviews.

Comment: Please stop asking the same question repeatedly. You could have just edited your original question (which would have put it back on the front page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add button in a listview you need two layout one layout is a listview and second layout is showing button which you want and with the help of this code you can show listview  with buttons.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                com.demo.list.R.layout.footerview, null);

        LinearLayout listHeaderView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                com.demo.list.R.layout.headerview, null);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        lv.addFooterView(listFooterView);
        lv.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);
```

here headerview and footerview is different layout in which i am showing buttons with listview.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. atleast u r better of those people who marking my post -vely :D